# How do I separate into a new cell in excel after every "-" in subject from outlook emails

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to get the string after a word that gives me the needed data and all the phrase after every "-"  into a new cell in excel except in RE: , where I omit "RE:" and only leave the TS... ticket ID.

This code works by selecting the emails in outlook and then running the macro for only that selected emails.

This is an example of a subject that has the

**Example Subject**

---

RE: TS001889493 - Translation failure - Inbound - ( VEXP/ HONCE/ Document Type 214 - Map AVE_NMHG_I_214_4010_XML_SAT - Error Conditional Relationship Error in N103 (0066)    [ ref:_00D50c9MW._5000z1J3cG8:ref ]

---

**Example of body**

Dear Valued Trading Partner,

We received the attached 214 transactions from   Sender ID: VEXP/  Receiver ID: HONCE that failed due to Conditional Relationship Error in the N1_03 (0066).

As per the map logic, If either N103 or N104 is present, then the other is required as they are in conditional relationship with each other.
But in the input file received, N104 value is missing hence the error.

Transaction Details: #4#
Attached

Please correct and resend the data.

Thank you,
Simon Huggs | Sass support - Basic

ref:_00D50c9MW._5000z1J3cG8:ref

---

What happens in the #num# is that it gets the sum of all these after making a match of the "TS" ticket ID.

This is the code I have up until now

```
Option Explicit
Sub WritingTicketNumberAndfailuresnew()
 Dim xlApp As Object
 Dim xlWB As Object
 Dim xlSheet As Object
 Dim rCount, STicket, SticketNumber As Long
 Dim bXStarted As Boolean
 Dim enviro As String
 Dim strPath, SSubject As String

 Dim currentExplorer As Explorer
 Dim Selection As Selection
 Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim obj As Object
 Dim strColS, strColB, sassupport, sMailDateReceived, SFrom As String


 Dim Actions1, Actions2, Actions3, Actions4 As Boolean
 Dim I, cnt, email_needed As Integer

' Get Excel set up
     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0

'Open a specific workbook to input the data the path of the workbook under the windows user account

     enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
     strPath = enviro & "\Documents\topthreeticket.xlsx"
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")


' Add column names
  xlSheet.Range("A1") = "Email Subject"
  xlSheet.Range("B1") = "Map Name"
  xlSheet.Range("C1") = "Case Number"
  xlSheet.Range("D1") = "No. Of Failures"
  xlSheet.Range("E1") = "Date"
  xlSheet.Range("F1") = "Week Number"


sassupport = "sassuport@sass.com"


On Error Resume Next
'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
rCount = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row
'needed for Exchange 2016. Remove if causing blank lines.
rCount = rCount + 1

' get the values from outlook
Set currentExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set Selection = currentExplorer.Selection
    For Each obj In Selection
    Set olItem = obj

'collect the fields for ticket number and failure count
    strColS = olItem.Subject
    strColB = olItem.Body
    SFrom = olItem.SenderEmailAddress
    sMailDateReceived = olItem.ReceivedTime

Dim sFailures, stmp1, stmp2, stmp3 As String
Dim RegX As Object, Mats As Object
Dim Found As Boolean

' Check the number of failures from body
   sFailures = "0"

   stmp1 = strColB
   Set RegX = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
   With RegX
       .Global = True
       .Pattern = "#\d+#"
       Set Mats = .Execute(stmp1)
   End With
   If (RegX.Test(stmp1)) Then
       stmp2 = Mats(0)
       Found = True
       stmp3 = Mid(stmp2, 2, Len(stmp2) - 2)
       sFailures = stmp3
    Else
       With RegX
          .Pattern = "#d\d+"
          Set Mats = .Execute(stmp1)
       End With
       If (RegX.Test(stmp1)) Then
           stmp2 = Mats(0)
           Found = True
           stmp3 = Mid(stmp2, 2, Len(stmp2) - 1)
           sFailures = stmp3
        End If
    End If

    Set Mats = Nothing
    Set RegX = Nothing

Dim tmp As String
Dim RegX2 As Object, Mats1 As Object

tmp = strColS
Set RegX2 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RegX2
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "TS00\d{7}"
    Set Mats1 = .Execute(tmp)
End With
If (RegX2.Test(tmp)) Then
   Set Mats1 = RegX2.Execute(tmp)
   tmp = Mats1(0)
Else
    With RegX2
      .Pattern = "T.S\d{9}"
      Set Mats1 = .Execute(tmp)
    End With
    If (RegX.Test(tmp)) Then
        tmp = Mats1(0)
    End If
End If
Set Mats1 = Nothing
Set RegX2 = Nothing



Dim tempticketnum, tmpdate As String
Dim ticketnumposition As Integer
'write them in the excel sheet
If SFrom = sassupport Then
    xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = strColS
    xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = tmp2
    xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = tmp
    xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = sFailures ' number of failures
    xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = sMailDateReceived
    rCount = rCount + 1
End If
Next

     Set olItem = Nothing
     Set obj = Nothing
     Set currentExplorer = Nothing
     Set xlSheet = Nothing
     Set xlWB = Nothing
     Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Look into "Text to Columns" using a "-" as your delimiter.

Comment: You also wanna capture `TS001889493` from your subject line?

Comment: @0m3r yes, but I am also separating it into another cell that only has ticket number

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SPLIT` function in VBA, something like so

```
Sub x()

Dim s As String
Dim a() As String

s = "this-will-test-this-out"

a = Split(s, "-")

Range("a1").Resize(UBound(a) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(a)

End Sub
```